# discord.py number of bans in a server

Tags: discord, discord.py

I was wondering how I can show how many bans a server has. For example if a server has 5 bans, How can I show that the server has 5 bans.

```
@client.command()
@commands.cooldown(1,3,BucketType.channel)
async def serverinfo(ctx):
  embed = discord.Embed(
    color = discord.Color(0xff3400),
    title = f"•{ctx.guild.name}•")
  embed.add_field(name="**•Server Created At•**", value=f"{ctx.guild.created_at.date()}", inline = False)
  embed.add_field(name="**✧Owner**", value=f"{ctx.guild.owner.mention}", inline = False)
  embed.add_field(name="**•Member Count•**", value=f"{len(ctx.guild.members)}", inline = False)
  embed.add_field(name = "**•Role Count•**", value = f"{len(ctx.guild.roles)}", inline = False)
  embed.add_field(name = "**•Channel + Category Count•**", value = f"{len(ctx.guild.channels)}", inline = False)
  embed.add_field(name = "**•Emoji Count•**", value = f"{len(ctx.guild.emojis)}", inline = False)
  embed.add_field(name = "**•Bans•**", value = f"{ctx.guild.bans}", inline = False)
  embed.set_thumbnail(url = f"{ctx.guild.icon_url}")
  embed.set_footer(icon_url = f"{ctx.author.avatar_url}", text = f"Requested by {ctx.author}")
  embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `len()` on the guild's bans

```py
len(await ctx.guild.bans())
```